# How to allocate memory for a String Dynamically?

Tags: c

I am trying to read Data from a Text file & storing it inside a structure having one char pointer & an int variable.
During fetching data from file I know that there will be one string to fetch & one integer value.
I also know the position form where I have to start fetching.
What I don't know is size of the string.
So, how can I allocate memory for that String.
Sample code is here :

```
struct filevalue
{
 char *string;
 int integer;
} value;    
fseek(ptr,18,SEEK_SET);//seeking from start of file to position from where I get String
fscanf(ptr,"%s",value.string);//ptr is file pointer

fseek(ptr,21,SEEK_CUR);//Now seeking from current position
fscanf(ptr,"%d",value.integer);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to know the required length, then use `malloc()` and remember to add one for null terminator.

Comment: Yeah but how I know the required length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

1. malloc the maximum possible length
2. read that much into the malloc'd block
3. figure out where the real end of the string is
4. write a `\0` into your malloc'd block there so it behaves correctly as a nul-terminated string (and/or save the length too in case you need it)
5. optionally realloc your block to the correct size

Or

1. malloc a reasonable guesstimate *N* for the length
2. read that much
3. if you can't find the end of the string in that buffer:

   1. grow the buffer with realloc to *2N* (for example) and read the next *N* bytes into the end
   2. goto 3
4. write a `\0` etc. as above

---

You said in a comment that the max. string length is bounded, so the first approach is probably fine.  You haven't said how you figure out where the string ends, but I'm assuming there is *some* delimiter, or it's right-filled with spaces, or something.

Comment: I didn't said that max. string size is bounded, But I can use you idea because in every file from where I have to access there is a common pattern I figured out that after every String (which I need) there is a newline character.I can check for it & can calculate the length.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to SEEK_CUR in your second fseek()?  if so, then you know the length of the string.  Used a fixed sized buffer.

Comment: The text which need to escape in file is of fixed length

Comment: So After I get string I can seek from that position to the position from where I have to take integer value. I mean the distance between string and Integer is fixed but string length is not fixed.

Comment: The string length is not fixed *but* there is a known upper limit - it can't be longer than the gap between the known start of string and known start of integer.  So assume the worst case and hard code that array size.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the position of the first structure, and the position of the second structure, you also know the total length of the first structure (*position of second* - *position of first*). You also know the size of the integer part of the structure, and therefore you can easily calculate the length of the string.

```
off_t pos1;  /* Position of first structure */
off_t pos2;  /* Position of second structure */

size_t struct_len = pos2 - pos1;
size_t string_len = struct_len - sizeof(int);
```

Comment: I know the size of text from end of string to start of integer & start of file to start of string.But size of text from start of file to start of integer value is again indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you open the file in binary mode since you use fseek.

you could read from the file using `fgetc()` since you don't know the size just allocate a buffer with some initial size like 100, then read char by char placing them into the buffer. monitor if the buffer is large enough to hold the characters and if not `realloc()` the buffer to a larger size.